# Won't spawn golems

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Playing creative mode minecraft on Xbox 360 and I've placed the iron blocks and jack o lantern to make a golem but a golem won't spawn,  I've made them before so I know how to but for some reason it won't spawn, advice on why?

Comment: Are you building it near other blocks?

Comment: The only blocks that are near it is grass blocks

Answer (score 1):

You have to place the pumpkin last and there can't be other blocks below the iron blocks on the side (next to the lower iron block).

Comment: I always put the pumpkin last. It's just not working for some reason

Comment: Then show more. Make a video or a series of screenshots. Since it works for other players, you have to show what's different with your approach, otherwise we can just tell you that it should work.